# Java: BigInteger floor and ceil functions

Tags: java, biginteger, floor, ceil

I'm trying to implement an RSA attack in Java and I need to compute math operations like floor and ceil to BigInteger variables. As we know math.ceil and math.floor only apply to double variables, do you know any other way I can compute floor and ceil for BigIntegers? Thank you.

Comment: So like `public static BigInteger floor(BigInteger x) { return x; }`, and same for "ceil"?

Comment: Um... just return the "Big **Integer**"?

Answer (score 1):

The question does not make sense: floor and ceil round a floating number to an integer. And guess what: BigInteger can only represent Integers. So no rounding required. (Esp. the RSA context emphasize the integer character).

Answer (score 1):

Since BigInteger values are integers, I assume that you want the the ceiling and floor of division operations. For that, I suggest that you use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead. It has a method `divide` that takes another BigDecimal and a [MathContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html). In the MathContext, you can specify the rounding mode as ceiling or floor (among others).

If all you need is rounding toward zero, you can also use `BigDecimal.divideToIntegralValue`.

Comment: However, the rounding mode does not have any effect on the result. Instead, use `BigDecimal.divide(other, RoundingMode.FLOOR)`.

Comment: @codesparkle - Yes, you can specify a rounding mode directly rather than through a `MathContext`. However, I don't understand your point about the rounding mode in the `MathContext` not having an effect. From [the docs for `divide(BigDecimal, MathContext)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20java.math.MathContext%29): _"Returns a `BigDecimal` whose value is (this / divisor), with rounding according to the context settings."_

Comment: your answer, though, refers to the `divideToIntegralValue` method, which ignores the rounding mode completely and always truncates the result.

Comment: @codesparkle - Wow. I completely missed that I was suggesting the wrong method. Good catch. I've edited my answer.