# Summing up huge fibonacci numbers (upto 10^18)

Tags: java, algorithm

I recently came across a problem where given a `l` and `r` you need to find out the sum of all x such that  l <= x <= r (mod10^9 + 7).

And,
`1 <= l <= r <= 10^18`

Let sum(x) be the sum of fibonacci numbers upto `x` and let fibo(x) be the `xth` fibonacci number. It is known that

```
sum(x) = fibo(x+2) - 1
```

Using this I used [this post](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/14516) to calculate the nth fibonacci term in O(logn) time. 
I was wondering if it can be done any faster than this. Below is my implementation

```
public class FastFibonacci {
    private static Map<BigInteger, BigInteger> map;
    private static BigInteger mod = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000007);


    public static BigInteger nthFibonacci(BigInteger num) {
        if (num.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2)) <= 0) return BigInteger.ONE;
       return solve(num.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10000));
    }

    public static BigInteger solve(BigInteger num) {
        if (map.get(num) != null) {
            return map.get(num);
        } else {
            BigInteger k = num.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
            if (num.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
                // f(2*k)
                map.put(num, (solve(k).multiply(solve(k)).mod(mod).add(solve(k.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(solve(k.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))).mod(mod)).mod(mod)));
                return map.get(num);
            } else {
                // f(2*k + 1)
                map.put(num, (solve(k).multiply(solve(k.add( BigInteger.ONE))).mod(mod).add(solve(k).multiply(solve(k.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))).mod(mod))).mod(mod));
                return map.get(num);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputReader in = new InputReader(System.in);
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE);
        map.put(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE);
        int test = in.nextInt();
        BigInteger[] ls = new BigInteger[test];
        BigInteger[] rs = new BigInteger[test];
        for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) {
            ls[i] = new BigInteger(in.readString());
            rs[i] = new BigInteger(in.readString());
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) {
            BigInteger sumUptoL = nthFibonacci(ls[i]).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            BigInteger sumUptoR = nthFibonacci(rs[i].add(BigInteger.valueOf(1))).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            sb.append(sumUptoR.subtract(sumUptoL));
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.print(sb.toString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for a given number N you only want to know fib(N+2)-1 and you don't really need to show all the sequence, you can use a non-recursive approach. The following function uses double, but you can refactor it to BigInteger to accept bigger values:

```
public double getFibonacci(int n) {
    double f1 = Math.pow(((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2.0), n);
    double f2 = Math.pow(((1 - Math.sqrt(5)) / 2.0), n);

    return Math.floor((f1 - f2) / Math.sqrt(5));
}
```

Comment: converting it to BigInteger doesnt work. There's no floor function for them

Comment: I guess because working with integers floor function makes no sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987155/java-biginteger-floor-and-ceil-functions

Comment: The result of the division will already be an integer, rounded down, so the "floor" operation is already done